# Firebase function error: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.keys (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

**Description of the problem:**

My App aim is to store family spending in Firebase Realtime Database. I want that, when a new spending is stored, a notification is sent to all other devices.
I try to send a notification to a single device and it works fine, but when I try to get all the tokens in an array, I have an error:
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.keys ().

**code of index.js** :

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
 admin.initializeApp();

exports.androidPushNotification = functions.database
    .ref("{nodo}/spese/{spesaPush}")
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
      const original = snapshot.val();

      const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database()
          .ref(`/utenti/{tutti}/token`).once('value');

      let tokensSnapshot;
      let tokens;
      tokensSnapshot = await getDeviceTokensPromise;

      // This is the line generating the errors. 
      // If I get only a specific token and 
      // use tokens = tokensSnapshot.val(); anything works fine
      tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());


      const result = original.chi + " ha speso " +
      original.costo + " € per acquistare " +
      original.desc;
      console.log(result);

      const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: 'New spending inserted!',
          body: result, 
        }
      };

      const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
      return result;
    });
```

It seems that values are not reached yet, but I thought that the keyword await lets system to wait until all data are available. From the log I noticed that the value I need is null and I don't understand why.
If I use this line of code:

```
      const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database()
          .ref(`/utenti/SpecificUser/token`).once('value');
      ....
      //then
      tokens = tokensSnapshot.val();
```

The notification is sent to the device that has the token under the name of "SpecificUser"

**EDIT:**
I provide a pic of my db. I notice that none of the field is null, so I don't know why I see this error [image]

Thank you to anyone that helps me

Comment: may you log a value returned from tokensSnapshot.val()?

Comment: The value is "null". For this reason I thought that the function has not "reached" yet the value

Comment: ok then there is all ok with awaits as you have data in object tokensSnapshot and even function val which for some reason returns null. It seems there is an issue inside db.

Comment: I edit the question putting a screenshot of the DB structure

Answer (score 0):

i had same error and it is solve by database...
when i saw my database values unfortunately i stored undefined value so my whole result got error like you...
see your whole values and fields that store values properly.

Comment: Nope, I see only real tokens

Comment: do you have any field that is deletedAt?

Comment: I don't think, anyway I have posted a pic of the db structure

Comment: problem is that your db didn't retrive all values that you want too.when you pass single token it give you result and when you pass multiple values it gives you error, so i strongly suggested to you as i experienced this type error, check your all db values that you want to retrive.